# mvn package + Nexus: Not authorized, ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized

Tags: java, maven, authorization, nexus, sonatype

I've got an "it's working on MY machine" - problem and I'm hoping to get some tips regarding what the causes could be. I'm NOT getting error 401, as I'm not trying to deploy something.

Our company has an internal nexus server for providing maven artifacts. There is an user 'readonly' configured which is not able to submit artifacts but can receive them. The problem is that the login is working on my machine but not on my co-workers.

We're using the same Maven projekt with exactly the same pom.xml which contains the following part:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>someId</id>
        <name>some Name</name>
        <url>theCorrectUrl</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Our settings.xml files are identical too. They contain the following:

```
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>someId</id>
        <username>readonly</username>
        <password>theCorrectPassword</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

As I said: We're using identical files. There are NO typos in the password or the username. But still I'm able to download dependencies from Nexus using "mvn package" but my co-worker is not.

Differences between our machines: He's using windows 7 and has maven version 3.5.4 installed. I'm using windows 10 and have version 3.5.2 installed. But that shouldn't be the problem, should it?

Note: My co-worker is able to reach the nexus server. It's not a routing/accessibility issue.

Are there any other configurations/files which I should check? What else could cause this problem?

Thanks in advance for any answer!

Comment: Do you have an authorization for downloading artifacts from nexus? I hope there is only a single group in Nexus configured furthermore can you show your settings.xml file?

Comment: @khmarbaise The <servers>-part of the settings.xml is in the question. The rest of the file is basically empty. What part do you want to see? Yes, the 'readonly'-user can download dependencies.

Comment: Use wireshark or similar to see the exact requests and replies, look for the differences and work backwards.

Comment: Could also check the request.log and see if that is returning a 401 or any other error code that might help troubleshoot further.